# Moment Generating Function exercises: Knowing that $M_{X}(0)=1$ and $M´_{X}(0)= EX$

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

[image]

Hi guys,

Any help with letter b of this exercise from Casella´s Book?

I could finish the letter a). But I cant move in letter b).

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: (b) implies that $M_X'(0)<0$, so that $M_X(t^*)=c<1$ for some $t^*$ near $t=0$.

Comment: @AlexR. So, Its just apply $t^{*}$ round zero, right? I will have: $P(S_{n} > a) <  \exp(-a.0)[M_{X}(t^{*})]^{n} = 1 . c^{n}$.